# Why is SCNPhysicsContact.collisionImpulse always 0.0?

Tags: ios, scenekit

I'm trying to find out the force of a collision in Scene Kit's physics engine. To keep things simple I'm using the following code:

```
extension MyScene: SCNPhysicsContactDelegate {
   func physicsWorld(_ world: SCNPhysicsWorld, didBegin contact: SCNPhysicsContact) {
      print("collisionImpulse=\(contact.collisionImpulse)")
   }
```

The function is called for each collision according to contactBitmasks and collisionBitmasks but each time I get contact.collisionImpulse=0.0

Is this a Scene Kit bug? am I doing something wrong?

I gave up trying to solve this and use the following instead:

```
    let factor: Float = 1.2
    let relativeVelocity = contact.nodeA.physicsBody!.velocity - contact.nodeB.physicsBody!.velocity
    let velMagnitude = relativeVelocity.length()
    let force = min(velMagnitude*factor, 1.0)
```

Helper function for SCNVector3 subtraction:

```
/// Vector subtract
func - (l: SCNVector3, r: SCNVector3) -> SCNVector3 {
    return SCNVector3(l.x-r.x, l.y-r.y, l.z-r.z)
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you ever find out what was wrong?

Comment: I did not. I use the workaround mentioned above, but it's not really a solution to the problem.

Comment: Finally found out why, check my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The collisionImpulse is not nil if you use "didEnd" or "didUpdate" instead of "didBegin":

```
func physicsWorld(_ world: SCNPhysicsWorld, didEnd contact: SCNPhysicsContact) {
      print("collisionImpulse=\(contact.collisionImpulse)")
}
```

my guess is that the values are not computed yet at the time of the didBegin call.

Comment: Thanks! This solves my problem, although in my case collisionImpulse was non-zero only inside didUpdate().